# add AVPlayerViewController view to external window

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I want to programmatically add an `AVPlayerViewController` view to an external window from an iPad. The problem is that when adding it, the player view says "This video is playing on the TV"

example code:

```
let player = AVPlayer(url: someUrl)
//these two properties seem to have no effect
//player.usesExternalPlaybackWhileExternalScreenIsActive = true/false
//player.allowsExternalPlayback = true/false
let viewController = AVPlayerViewController()
viewController.player = player
viewController.view.frame = frame
externalWindow.addSubview(viewController.view)
player.play()
```

Is there a way to add the video view myself to the external window so I can decide the size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to control the size of the AVPlayerViewController you can use the layer or you can add it as a childViewController

Using Layer

```
let videoURL = URL(url to your file)
let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
player.play()
```

In the above code the frame can be adjusted as per the requirement.

Using ChildViewController:

```
let videoURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath)
let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
playerViewController.view.frame = CGRect(give the appropriate size)
playerViewController.player = player  

self.addChildViewController(playerViewController)
self.view.addSubview(playerViewController.view)
playerViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Let me know if this helps!! or anything else is needed.